# Can't seem to widgetize a sidebar for a custom Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I was brought in to make a quick Wordpress theme for a client's existing site. Using the existing site's CSS and JS, and skeleton HTML, I was able to get the theme working in virtually every way except some. For starters, I can't seem to 'widgetize' the sidebar.

The HTML for the sidebar, before attempting to register for widgets, was as follows:

```
<div class="wms-column wms-column-nav">
    <div class="wms-column-nav-body">
      <h2><a href="/">Blog</a></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bear in mind that I can add html inside of the inner div, but I cannot change the two outer divs. They must remain.

After reading http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes and trying several examples, I get nothing but errors. Naturally, the widget area therefore refuses to show in Dashboard > Appearances.

How do I convert the above code to function as a widget-accepting sidebar? Is having id="sidebar" necessary? And are titles needed? The Codex page seems to imply the way you format the titles depends on the overall approach (example: divs vs. lists). The impression I am getting is that you're making a template that the widgets use over and over to kick out content. I figured you just were telling WP where to put widgets (and all of their content / format / intricacies were handling in the widget's code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widgetizing a theme a basically two steps.

1. Register your sidebar
2. Add the registered sidebar to the theme

### In `functions.php`

[From the Codex page for `register_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar);

```
 register_sidebar(array(
   'name' => __( 'Right Hand Sidebar' ),
   'id' => 'right-sidebar',
   'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on the right-hand side.' ),
   'before_title' => '<h1>',
   'after_title' => '</h1>'
 ));
```

### In your theme template(s)

Add a call to [`dynamic_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar). This would probably be in `sidebar.php`

```
<div class="wms-column wms-column-nav">
    <div class="wms-column-nav-body"><?php
      dynamic_sidebar( 'right-sidebar' ); // your widgets will go here ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that the parameter used in `dynamic_sidebar` matches the `id` used when registering the sidebar. That should be it. Of course, implementations can be more complicated-- including for example a hard-coded fallback sidebar or multiple sidebars-- but that is the basic started pack.